# PCIe Legacy Interrupts for Integrated GbE Controller

Tags: x86, interrupt, ethernet, drivers, pci-e

I am writing ethernet drivers for GbE Controller for Autosar which is a pcie device(20) for intel x86 based platform, So far I have been able to configure IOAPIC for timer and GPIO interrupts but I am unable to receive PCIe legacy interrupts on IOAPIC.
I have verfied following configurations

1. PCIe configuration space to verify legacy interrupts are enable in Command Register (offset 0x4)
2. Verified that ethernet controller is generating interrupt by status register in configuration space (offset 0x6) and Internal register which indicates that a valid interrupts is generated for ethernet controller
3. I have mapped INTA to IOAPIC IRQ16 (note :INTA-D are mapped to PIRQA-PIRQH by IR registers) by IR20 (interrupt routing)  registers in ILB and disabled its routing to 8259 PIC by PIRQA register.

Kindly let me know what am I missing in mapping interrupts and also let me know if I am missing anything from question? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try MSI interrupts instead of legacy?

Comment: We might have to support both. But for now I haven't tested MSI.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what resolved the issue, I mapped INTA to IRQ17(PIRQB) which resolved the issue. Still not able to receive interrupt on IRQ16(PIRQA)